# Mesh becomes grainy after importing node group

Tags: texturing, node-editor

So i've followed a YT video about exporting your node groups for later use.
However when I import the node group in a new file, the texture becomes all grainy.
[image: Original file]

[image: New file]

[image]

Comment: You should really add an image of the *contents* of the group. What does the group contain?

Comment: Added the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try mixing the noise texture in the left bottom corner with generated texture coordinate instead of object texture coordinate because by default your noise texture uses generated texture coordinate. Another option is to plug the object coordinate into the vector input of the noise texture.
[image: Option 1]

or

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping, i'll give this a try